# grab serial input line and move them to a shell script

Tags: python, shell, variables, os.system

I tries to grab a uart - line and give this string to a shell script;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 4800)
while True :
 try:
    state=ser.readline()
    print(state)
 except:
    pass
```

So, "state" should given to a shell script now, 
like: `myscript.sh "This is the serial input..."`
but how can I do this?

```
print(os.system('myscript.sh ').ser.readline())
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `os.system()` doesn't return anything you want to `print`.  If the subprocess prints anything to standard output, that's where it'll go, and your Python script won't know.  If you want to capture what the subprocess prints, you have yet another reason to look at the `subprocess` module instead, specifically the `check_output` method (Python 2.7+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple string concatenation passed to the os.system function.

```
import os
os.system("myscript.sh " + ser.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to combine two strings (namely `"./myscript.sh"` and `ser.readLine()`), which will then give you the full command to be run by use of `os.system`. E.g. strings can be arguments of the `string.format` method:

```
os.system('myscript.sh {}'.format(ser.readline()))
```

Also you can just add two strings:

```
os.system('myscript.sh '+ser.readline())
```

I am not sure what you want to achieve with the `print` statement. A better way to handle the call and input/output of your code would be to switch from os to the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

If `myscript` can continuously read additional input, you have a much more efficient pipeline.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
sink = Popen(['myscript.sh'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
while True:
    sink.communicate(ser.readline())
```

If you have to start a new `myscript.sh` for every input line, (you'll really want to rethink your design, but) you can, of course:

```
while True:
    subprocess.check_call(['myscript.sh', ser.readline())
```

Notice how in both cases we [avoid a pesky shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).

Comment: Thanks, - yes, I'd start a new script for each input line, because there are only few lines a day and I need the ability to change the process script, without interrupt the read - line process, so since 5 years ago, I decided to made two scripts, one for reading and one for testing the lines. But the shell script for reading doesn't worked at the new hw (pi 3), so I'm searching a new "reading" script, now.